# Is it possible to get streaming url with Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have my own video player with in my app and want to play in it if I can get a video url. Is it possible with Vimeo API?

In my app I will allow users to search for videos and play it on my media player on mobile.

Answer (score 8):

API requests authenticated as a PRO user will have access to that users video files. This includes the transcoded files and an HLS link. You can find these urls in the video representation, returned by many different api calls. Specifically under the `files` key, you will find an array containing the url and additional metadata. Make sure to pick your video based on the resolution, and not the quality, because the quality can have duplicate

The most relevant api call is `GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`, because this will return a list of all videos owned by the authenticated user (which happen to be the only videos with available video files).

Video files are not available for basic or Plus users, and are not available for users beyond the one making the request. For those videos you should use the embed codes we provide in the API request (under the key `response.embed.html`, or through [oEmbed](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed).

Comment: Thankyou. Let me check on pro version. From your answer I see i can get the video link even im not the owner. Any usage limitations in pro version regarding api calls?

Comment: The authenticated user can only see video links if they are the owner. So your access tokens can not see other users videos. But other users using your app can see their own videos. For more informatino about rate limits, check out https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines

Comment: ohh I see! In that case I cannot use in my app as I need direct link to play the video on a texture :( . I need to provide a way to let users search for video and play specific video on a texture.

Comment: "You can find these urls in the video representation, returned by many different api calls." Which ones specifically?

Comment: It should be part of the default video representation, which is returned from any api call for videos. This includes direct lookups, videos in an album, video search, etc. I haven't worked with the Vimeo API for years though, so this may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If your videos are set to public you can hit the endpoint...

[https://player.vimeo.com/video/{your_video_id}/config](https://player.vimeo.com/video/%7Byour_video_id%7D/config).

This will return a json. In the nested field request > files > progressive, you will have objects that contains streaming urls.

There is also dash and hls streaming formats under the files node, but not sure if all players will support those formats.